# Linux network adapter keeps changing settings

Tags: linux, networking, centos, connection, ethernet

I'm running CentOS 5 and noticed for the past week that eth0 settings keep changing and I have to reset them.

Any ideas what it might be or where I need to start?

Comment: David, is ipaddress is getting change or duplex mode is getting change?

Comment: ip is getting changed at least (I don't know what duplex mode is [noob])

Comment: iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport some_port -j LOG then
tail -f /var/log/messages
Afterwards, to see how much data has been hit by that rule: iptables -L -n -v
Or you could run tcpdump and grep out the ports.

Comment: I reckon this happens sometime in the middle of the night. Is there a way to log changes to the network configuration?

Comment: David, if this is a static ipaddress then same one changing manually.

Comment: yes, static...however, I don't think its someone, but something....im trying to figure out what this something is.

Comment: is this not network manager being a pain ? If so, try killing it off and see if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bet is on the NetworkManager service...